# How to turn off a spinner directive in angularjs for a specific $http requests

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This directive will simply turn it on/off for a loading icon automatically. when $http requests occurs

**My code**

```
angular.module('directive.loading', [])
        .directive('loading',   ['$http' ,function ($http)
        {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
                {
                    scope.isLoading = function () {
                        return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
                    };

                    scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
                    {
                        if(v){
                            elm.show();
                        }else{
                            elm.hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

        }]);
```

**My html code**

```
<div class="loading-spiner-holder" data-loading ><div class="loading-spiner"><img src="..." /></div></div>
```

My scenario was how to turn off for a specific request in a page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a condition and then change it via the rootscope. Before your ajax request, you simply call $rootScope.$emit('stopLoader');

```
angular.module('directive.loading', [])
    .directive('loading',   ['$http', '$rootScope',function ($http, $rootScope)
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
            {
                scope.isNoLoadingForced = false;
                scope.isLoading = function () {
                    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0 && scope.isNoLoadingForced;
                };

                $rootScope.$on('stopLoader', function(){
                    scope.isNoLoadingForced = true;
                })

                scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
                {
                    if(v){
                        elm.show();
                    }else{
                        elm.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    }]);
```

This is definatly not the best solution but it would still works.

Comment: you need to inject the $rootScope dependences to your function

Comment: also, it's `$on` and `$emit` my bad.

Comment: there, i changed my answer.